# Passing parameter inside the groovy script in mule4

Tags: curl, groovy, mule, mule4

I am trying to parameterize the username and password through .properties file in mule.
The groovy script has curl command. I have defined VID and VPASS in the parameters section of the execute component and passing it inside the script as shown below. At run time it is not able to resolve the id and password. How to pass the parameters here inside the curl command.

def proctext = 'curl -H "apiAccessKeyId: **+ vid"** -H "apiSecretAccessKey**:+vpass**" -H "Accept:application/json" --form "file=@C:\Files\test.csv" --form "params={Type:Import}" -X POST http://mysuperserver/media/upload/'

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61928860/how-to-call-curl-command-from-mule4 you asked for something quite similar and the accepted answer stated, that using curl is a bad idea.

Comment: That approach seems to be good but it is not working out for me, i am facing some issues there.Trying other possible solution

Comment: I recommend that you write a question with the details of what the other answer is not working.

Comment: ok @aled . I shall post the question in sometime

Comment: But can i get the answer for this? it will be useful learning for me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the parameters in the [parameters element of the Scripting Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/scripting/scripting-module#setting-parameters), as a DataWeave expression.

```
<flow name="groovy-paramsFlow" >
    <http:listener doc:name="Listener" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/"/>
    <set-variable value="#[123]" doc:name="Set Variable" variableName="myVar"/>
    <scripting:execute doc:name="Execute" engine="groovy">
        <scripting:code ><![CDATA[def proctext = 'curl -H "apiAccessKeyId: ' + vid + '" -H "apiSecretAccessKey: ' + vpass +'" -H "Accept:application/json" --form "file=@C:\\Files\\test.csv" --form "params={Type:Import}" -X POST http://mysuperserver/media/upload/']]></scripting:code>
        <scripting:parameters ><![CDATA[#[{ vid: "abcd", vpass: "efgh" }]
        ]]></scripting:parameters>
    </scripting:execute>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Payload #[payload]"/>
</flow>
```

Output

```
Payload curl -H "apiAccessKeyId: abcd" -H "apiSecretAccessKey: efgh" -H "Accept:application/json" --form "file=@C:\Files\test.csv" --form "params={Type:Import}" -X POST http://mysuperserver/media/upload/
```

Comment: I am able to understand how to pass the parameter to the script.But inside the curl command it is not able to resolve the parameters actual value.I am suspecting, this could be because of quotes.Not sure though

Comment: I had problems with the quotes in the past, but here it was the backlashes (`\`). Note that you have not only the problems of Groovy language and also its interaction with the Mule XML files. Also the parameters where not out of the strings, so they were literals rather than treated as variables. I have updated my example to match yours. HINT: always put the complete error messages in your questions. They have the clues in many cases.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters For Groovy Script

There are two ways to pass values to Groovy scripts in and out https://simpleflatservice.com/mule4/ParametersForGroovyScripts.html

One way is to use regular variables. In Groovy script they are attributes of the variable vars.
Another way is to set attributes of the script. In this way the variables could be used by their names directly.
The way out is similar. Whatever is last statement of the script became payload after Groovy script. To ouput variable values the attributes of vars should be chnaged.
Variable vars is unchangable so now new attributes could be added but attrinutes themselves are changeable and could carry out any values.

Word of caution - by default Mule tries to use streams and may provide some difficulaties for interactions. For example if variable in Mule is JSON it could be a stream and so no attribuets in stream could be chnaged inside Groovy script. In this case it is better to set variable as Java and then attributes are available for change.

[image]

Groovy script component
[image]

Whole flow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db"
    xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting"

 xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"

 xmlns:email="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email" xmlns:wsc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc" xmlns:ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd

http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/core/current/mule-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/wsc/current/mule-wsc.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/email/current/mule-email.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">

 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_config" doc:name="HTTP Listener config" doc:id="f7458033-5606-4521-ae2b-7c309c34bdb2" >

  <http:listener-connection host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" />

 </http:listener-config>

 <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_configuration" doc:name="HTTP Request configuration" doc:id="13190c91-83f0-40bf-8288-1f1f330c0b48" >

  <http:request-connection host="localhost" port="8081" />

 </http:request-config>
    <email:smtp-config name="Email_SMTP" doc:name="Email SMTP" doc:id="45eb1460-05a9-41c5-80be-344a45b241e0" >
        <email:smtp-connection host="smtp.kclife.net" user="alex.kizub" password="8Abc#135" />
    </email:smtp-config>
    <flow name="workFlow" doc:id="ea9b69db-5516-4940-a81c-b88c3415c75d" >
        <http:listener doc:name="Listener" doc:id="81680002-4376-47d1-ada6-a4f18f978b36" config-ref="HTTP_Listener_config" path="/"/>
        <ee:transform doc:name="set myRegularVariable    and    myCollection" doc:id="e79005e0-6652-4cc6-8f83-807fc0432ed0" >
            <ee:message >
            </ee:message>
            <ee:variables >
                <ee:set-variable variableName="myRegularVariable" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
'Hello']]></ee:set-variable>
                <ee:set-variable variableName="myCollection" ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output application/java
---
{
    start: now()
}]]></ee:set-variable>
            </ee:variables>
        </ee:transform>
        <scripting:execute engine="groovy" doc:name="Execute Groovy script" doc:id="b465ab5c-d2b7-4d86-860a-f0097aa30da4" >
            <scripting:code ><![CDATA[def string=vars.myRegularVariable + ' ' + myInScriptVaraiable
vars.myCollection['result']=string
string + '!' // return as payload]]></scripting:code>
            <scripting:parameters ><![CDATA[#[{myInScriptVaraiable:'World'}]]]></scripting:parameters>
        </scripting:execute>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log payload" doc:id="1f8b99ef-a4ce-42ec-8a2b-0b0e31b4128f" message="#[payload]"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Log myCollection" doc:id="2cdd252d-3993-4dd5-b897-2456761ad293" message="#[vars.myCollection]"/>
    </flow>

</mule>
```